# How can i add library to my cocos2d-x Game

Tags: cocos2d-x

I copy jar file to libs

> cocos2d-x-3.6\MyGame\proj.android\libs\armeabi

and the jar file name is

> adad-2.9.jar

How can i add this to my android.mk too?

Answer (score 0):

put the jar file in cocos2d-x-3.6\MyGame\proj.android\libs only.
no change in android.mk is required for jar files.